# Software to take a picture via webcam every X time (e.g. every 20 minutes), over an extended period of time (multiple weeks)

Tags: windows, gratis, photography, webcam, timer

I have a project where I need to consistently be able to capture pictures (preferrably timestamped) over the course of a longer period. I have found some options but many of them either cost, or have limitations for the maximum time and are intended for shorter duration.

Would there be some software that could do this?

Comment: No Windows system runs so long :-) I can't recommend anything, but "timelapse" might be a good term for starting a search

Comment: If you're a programmer (or have one), it's easy to write code to capture images in a Timer event and save them named as the capture Date-Time such as `2023-05-19-2215.jpg`. To do the capturing, you'll need an API with webcame support. There are free options as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750879). If you need a professional API that's well-documented with code samples and free technical support, you could try the LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK. (Disclosure: I work for the its vendor). There's a free evaluation [on this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: There's this script with PowerShell that you could try; https://github.com/stefanstranger/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-WebCamp.ps1 But it's a bit dated and might not work.

Comment: A long time ago I used [webcamXP](https://www.webcamxp.com/products.aspx) to do this kind of stuff.